# Selenium WebDriver: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

This is my Selenium browser test class (a derived one, but should not be hard to understand what it is doing). When I run the test case, all interactions occur as expected. But in the end the result of test case shows a failure.

```
package dmswebui.CR;

import org.infineta.webui.selenium4j.MainTestCase;

public class TestLogin extends MainTestCase {

  @Override
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    startSeleniumSession("ChromeDriver", "http://192.168.8.207/");
  }

  public void testMethod() throws Exception {

        session().open("/");
        session().type("name=user","admin");
        session().type("name=password","infineta123");
        session().click("id=btnLogin-button");      session().waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        session().click("id=btnUserLogout-button");
        session().click("id=yui-gen0-button");      session().waitForPageToLoad("30000");
  }
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        closeSeleniumSession();
  }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Testcase: testMethod took 13.939 sec
Caused an ERROR
Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

Comment: I see you seem to be trying to connect to a remote address. Why is this? What happens if it is run at your own machine?

Comment: This usually happens when you are trying to close the same webdriver instance multiple times. Do you know what happens in super.teardown()? When I checked the selenium4j source, it extends junit Testcase. You can try putting that closeSeleniumSession() before super.tearDown(). That might fix the issue. BTW, never knew about selenium4j.. Interesting project

Comment: @A.J: bang on target...if u can put that into answer...I am willing to accept it :)

Comment: What is in your closeSeleniumSession method? I am having the same Error communicating to browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens when you are trying to close the same webdriver instance multiple times. Do you know what happens in `super.teardown()`? When I checked the selenium4j source, it extends junit Testcase. Your `super.tearDown` will be calling jUnitTeardown and would be killing the browser instance before `closeSeleniumSession()` is called.

You can put that `closeSeleniumSession()` before `super.tearDown()`.